# R write.table not writing actual values

Tags: r

I have a data.frame in R that looks something like this:

```
head(genotypesMin2SNPS)

## V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 V21
## V3  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
## V4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
##                                 V1       V1
## V3   0   0    0    0    0       WASH7P  1_14677
## V4   0   0    0    0    0       WASH7P  1_14684
## V5   0   0    0    0    0       WASH7P  1_14685
## V6   0   0    0    0    0       WASH7P  1_14711
## V8   0   0    0    0    0 LOC100288069 1_721355
```

Here is the output of `dput(droplevels(head(genotypesMin2SNPS)))`:

```
structure(list(V1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V2 = c(1L, 0L, 
 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), genes = structure(list(V1 = structure(c(22691L, 
22691L, 22691L, 22691L, 10920L, 10920L), .Label = c("A1BG", "A1BG-AS1", 
"A1CF", "A2M", "A2ML1", "A3GALT2", "A4GALT", "A4GNT", "AAAS",

.
.
.
), class = "factor")), .Names = "V1", row.names = c(3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 8L, 9L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("V1", "V2", 
"V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10", "V11", "V12", 
"V94", "V95", "V96", "V97", "V98", "V99", "V100", "V101", "V102", 
"genes", "snps"), row.names = c("V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V8", 
"V9"), class = "data.frame")
```

When I use `write.table()` I get this:

```
"V83474" 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
 0 0         
c(22691, 22691, 22691,22691, 10920, 10920, 10920, 10920, 10920, 6668, 6668, 10493, 10493, 10493, 10493,
```

I think that the columns were added as individual data.frames, could this be the problem?

Comment: hi, could you add `dput(head(genotypesMin2SNPS))` and he code you used to write out please

Comment: Do you mean write.table(dput(head(genotypesMin2SNPS)) ? Sorry an R noob

Comment: No, sorry if i was unclear...  could you edit your question with the output of `dput(droplevels(head(genotypesMin2SNPS)))` - this will allow us to see the structure of your data. Also add the code that you used to export your data, as in .`write.table(genotypesMin2SNPS, ... )`

Comment: Still not getting a neat tab sep file
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V101 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V102 = c(0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), genes = structure(list(V1 = structure(c(22691L,
22691L, 22691L, 22691L, 10920L, 10920L), .Label = c("A1BG", "A1BG-AS1",
"A1CF", "A2M", "A2ML1", "A3GALT2", "A4GALT", "A4GNT", "AAAS",
"AAAS,C12orf10", "AACS", "AADAC", "AADACL2", "AADACL2-AS1", "AADACL2-AS1,MIR548H2",
"AADACL3", "AADACL4", "AADAT", "AAED1", "AAGAB", "AAGAB,IQCH",

Comment: I think the problem lies in how I created the data frame. As the issue seems two be with the two end columns that I added with  genotypesMin2SNPS$new <-  new <- read.table(file="new.txt")

Comment: ok, you can look at the structure of your data with `str(genotypesMin2SNPS)` and see if it is as you expect. I cant offer anything more, as your `dput` was incomplete.

Comment: run `sapply(data, class)`.  Are any of them `"list"`? Also please edit in the original question as it has been deleted.

Comment: No, they where all "integer" and two were "data.frame"